# Save comments to firebase and appear in UItableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a tableview and you can create a comment by typing in commentTextField and I save this to firebase and the comments appear in firebase... I also have the comments appearing in the table view after they press send... The only problem I have is when I exit the tableview and come back the comment is gone it is not saved in the tableview... but it still appears in firebase. Below is my code for sending and saving data to firebase and uitableview.

```
func loadData() {
        ref.child("Comments").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.messages.removeAll()
            snapshot.children.forEach({ (child) in
                if let obj = (child as? DataSnapshot)?.value as? [String : Any] {
                    if let author = obj["author"] as? String, let text = obj["text"] as? String {
                        let message = Message(author: author, comment: text)
                        self.messages.append(message)
                    }
                }
            })
           self.chatTableViewController.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = chatTableViewController.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableChatCell
        let comment = messages[indexPath.row]
        cell.usernameForChat.text = comment.author
        cell.loadCommentToView.text = comment.comment
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }
    func tableViewDataLoad() {
        chatTableViewController?.delegate = self
        chatTableViewController?.dataSource = self
        chatTableViewController?.reloadData()
    }
    @IBAction func handleSend(_ sender: Any) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Comments")
        let childRef = ref.childByAutoId()
        if let author = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName, let text = commentTextField.text {
            let values = ["author": author, "text": text]
            let aMessage = Message(author: author, comment: text)
            self.messages.append(aMessage)
            chatTableViewController.reloadData()
            childRef.updateChildValues(values)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think your tableView reload before the data is being fetched to messages array try self.chatTableViewController.reloadData() pasting this line just next to your self.messages.append(message) and call your  loadData() in willAppear() id still issue exist I will look for another solution

Comment: @iOSGeek thank you.. I am testing now

Comment: @iOSGeek nothing happend... same issue

Comment: where are you calling `loadData()`?

Comment: @eshirima viewdidload()

Comment: @eshirima I dont get why the comments to not load... they save in firebase

Comment: I assume you're calling `tableViewDataLoad()` in `viewDidLoad()` as well right?

Comment: If yes, in your `viewDidLoad()`, in what order are `tableViewDataLoad()` and `loadData()` getting called?

Comment: loadData() tableViewDataLoad()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149420/discussion-between-eshirima-and-kim-riegel).